# How to get palindrome using python

Tags: python-2.7

This code reverses the number correctly but I am always getting return type as false, even though the number is palindrome. e.g 141. What is missing/wrong here?

```
def f (x,rem = 0) :

    while x>0 :

        rem = rem*10 + x%10
        x=x//10
        continue
    return rem == x
```

Comment: You are altering `x` during the function, so checking `rem==x` at the end is not going to check if `rem` is equal to your original number.

Comment: Also, `continue` at the end of your loop is not doing anything. Loops continue without being told.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can you help me with writing the correct code, so that it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to confirm that `rem` is equal to your original number by comparing it to `x`. But `x` is zero, because the `while` loop ensures that. The way to fix that problem is something like this:

```
def f(x):
    original = x
    rem = 0
    while x>0:
        rem = rem*10 + x%10
        x = x//10
    return (rem==original)
```

i.e. store the original value before you alter it, so you still have it to compare to `rem` at the end.